# php mvc update images

Tags: php, image, model-view-controller, edit

I have some questions about editing multiple images on my custom PHP MVC code.

Here is **controller**:

```
public function izmijeniProizvod() {
    $item['item_id'] = $_POST['item_id'];
    $item['title'] = $_POST['title'];
    $item['description'] = $_POST['description'];
    $item['price'] = $_POST['price'];
    $item['fk_category_id'] = $_POST['fk_category_id'];
    $item['fk_sub_category_id'] = $_POST['fk_sub_category_id'];
    $item['active'] = $_POST['active'];
    $item['sifra_proizvoda'] = $_POST['sifra_proizvoda'];
    $item['image'] = !empty($_FILES['image']['name'][0]) ? $_FILES['image']['name'][0] : '';
    $imageFile = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $imageFolder = BASE_PATH.'cdn/proizvodi/' . $item['item_id'] . '/';

    $result = $this-> model-> updateItem($item); 



    for($i = 0; $i < count($imageFile); $i++) :
        $item['image'] = !empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]) ? $_FILES['image']['name'][$i] : '';


        if (!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]) && $_FILES['image']['error'][$i] == 0 && $_FILES['image']['size'][$i] > 0) :
            require_once APP . 'PHPThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php';

            if (!is_dir($imageFolder)) :
                mkdir($imageFolder);
            endif;

            if (is_dir($imageFolder)) {
                array_map('unlink', glob($imageFolder . '*'));
            }


                foreach ($this->thumbs as $thumb) :
                    $newImageFile = $thumb['width'] . 'x' . $thumb['height'] . '_' . $imageFile[$i];
                    $phpThumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);
                    $phpThumb->resize($thumb['width'], $thumb['height'])->save($imageFolder . $newImageFile); //cuva sliku
                endforeach;
                    $this-> model-> updateSlike($item, $imageFile[i]);


        endif;
    endfor;
```

And **model** for this part of code is:

```
public function updateItem($item) {
    $imageSql = !empty($item['image']) ? " , `image` = '{$item['image']}' " : '';

    $sql = "UPDATE `items` SET `title` = '{$item['title']}', `active` = '{$item['active']}' , `sifra_proizvoda` = '{$item['sifra_proizvoda']}' , `description` = '{$item['description']}', `price` = '{$item['price']}',
                   `fk_category_id` = '{$item['fk_category_id']}', `fk_sub_category_id` = '{$item['fk_sub_category_id']}'
                   $imageSql
            WHERE `item_id` = '{$item['item_id']}'";
    $result = $this->db->exec($sql);
    return $result;

}

public function updateSlike($item){
    //$slika = count($item['image']);

    $sql = "UPDATE `slike_proizvoda` SET `slika1` = '{$item['image']}' WHERE `item_id` = '{$item['item_id']}'";
    $result = $this->db->exec($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

**View** part of code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Slika:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <?php if (!empty($this->item['images']['300x300'])) { ?>
      <img id="slika" alt="<?php echo $this->item['image']; ?>"  src="<?php echo $this->item['images']['300x300'] ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="help-block">
      <p>
        <label for="image">Izmijeni glavnu sliku:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">
        <input type="hidden" name="image[]" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="image2">Ubaci još jednu sliku:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">
        <input type="hidden" name="image[]" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="image3">Ubaci još jednu sliku:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">
        <input type="hidden" name="image[]" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Things I get with this parts of code is:
only one imaget get upload, on updateSlike() get only one image name in mysql ...

Thanks.

Comment: Change `$this-> model-> updateSlike($item, $imageFile[i]);` to `$this-> model-> updateSlike($item, $imageFile[$i]);`

Comment: And, all `<.. type='file' .. id="image"..>` is having same ID.  I think, you have heard about it "*IDs can't be same through out the same page. It must be unique*"

Comment: Ah, its not that kind of error. I think I typed only here " i " wrong. So, I get last image in mysql base, and also last image get uplaod.

Comment: "*..I think I typed only here " i " wrong.*". Please don't type wrong here. People spend their time and put efforts to solve all your problem. This will be time consuming for us to assume that typo must not be the case.

Comment: If, it's taking the last image. Then, may be because your ID is not unique.

Comment: And, wait. Why `<input type="hidden" name="image[]" />` this?

Comment: @NanaPartykar $item_id is unique, <input type="hidden" name="image[]" /> because I think that part of code I used when I adding image, and it works.

Comment: I'm talking about `id="image"` in `<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">`.